# How to install Plaid ML on macOS

Tags: macos, python

So I am trying to install plaid ML on macOS (so I can do machine learning with tensor flow on the GPU). Installing it with `pip install -U plaidml-keras` works, but then when I run `plaidml-setup` (as the instructions say), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/plaidml-setup", line 6, in <module>
    from plaidml.plaidml_setup import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    import plaidml.settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidml/settings.py", line 33, in <module>
    _setup_config('PLAIDML_EXPERIMENTAL_CONFIG', 'experimental.json')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidml/settings.py", line 30, in _setup_config
    'Could not find PlaidML configuration file: "{}".'.format(filename))
plaidml.exceptions.PlaidMLError: Could not find PlaidML configuration file: "experimental.json".
```

the instructions that I was using are https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/blob/master/docs/install.rst#macos

I didn't do the virtual environment part because I don't think that the overhead is worth it.

Comment: You are missing "experimental.json"

Comment: @DavidPostill but where do I put it, and what should be in it???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set environment path for **plaidml**. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60016869/6117565) post on StackOverflow.